# Matlab: Overlay a 3D surface with a transparent texture

Tags: matlab

I would like to overlay some height data with some intensity data in a 3D-view. It is easy in 2D (see the first image generated by the code below), but in 3D the representations look somewhat weird, see second and third image in the example below. I would like the dots in the rgb image look more "solid".

```
figure;
subplot(1,3,1);
% Get some data
[x,y,z] = peaks(128);
pos = (rand(2,5).*4)-2;
i = zeros(128,128);
for n = 1:5
    i = i+exp(-((((x-pos(1,n))/.2).^2+(((y-pos(2,n)))/.2).^2))); 
end

% Convert to uin16 since real data is uint16
i = i./max(i(:));
i = i * 2^16;
i = uint16(i);

i_rgb = ind2rgb(i, hot(2^16));

% Display data

% This is how it should look like in 3D

imagesc(z);
colormap(gray);
axis image;
hold on;

img = imshow(i_rgb);
img.AlphaData = i;

% now in 3D, here the texture looks strange

subplot(1,3,2);

s = surface(x,y,z);
s.EdgeColor = 'none';
axis ij tight equal off; colormap(gray);

hold on; 

s2 = surface(x,y,z);
s2.EdgeColor = 'none';
s2.FaceColor = 'texturemap';
s2.CData = i_rgb;
s2.FaceAlpha = 'texturemap';
s2.AlphaData = i;
hold off;

% Again in 3D, but without FaceAlpha = 'texturemap';
% The intensity-dots look good, but the remaining area looks strange.
subplot(1,3,3);

s3 = surface(x,y,z);
s3.EdgeColor = 'none';
axis ij tight equal off; colormap(gray);

s4 = surface(x,y,z);
s4.EdgeColor = 'none';
s4.FaceColor = 'texturemap';
s4.CData = i_rgb;
s2.AlphaData = i;
```

[image: left: looks fine, but 2D only. center: a lot of gaps in the intensity image. right: right: the surface underneath looks weird.]

*Update*: System information:

OS: SuSE Linux 42.1

```
>> version

ans =

    '9.2.0.538062 (R2017a)'

>> opengl info
                          Version: '4.5.0 NVIDIA 375.66'
                           Vendor: 'NVIDIA Corporation'
                         Renderer: 'Quadro K1000M/PCIe/SSE2'
                   MaxTextureSize: 16384
                           Visual: 'Visual 0x27, (RGBA 32 bits (8 8 8 8), Z depth 16 bits, Hardware acceleration, Double buffer, Antialias 8 samples)'
                         Software: 'false'
             HardwareSupportLevel: 'full'
        SupportsGraphicsSmoothing: 1
    SupportsDepthPeelTransparency: 1
       SupportsAlignVertexCenters: 1
                       Extensions: {330×1 cell}
               MaxFrameBufferSize: 16384
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your (bad) figures. Could you specify your OS, matlab version, OpenGL version? To check if it is an OpenGL problem, try switching to software rendering using `opengl software`.

Comment: I have added my system data in an update. Using software rendering makes the central image look a bit better, but there are still gaps when  I rotate it.

Comment: Is this the desired result: https://imgur.com/a/cFdxh?

Comment: Maybe. Please try something like `view(45,45)` on the second image to see how the intensity-image looks in 3D. It should be without any gaps.

Comment: Not sure it will solve your problem but if you have a look at the questions and answers here: [Drawing atop a surface plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056735/matlab-drawing-atop-a-surface-plot/40105061#40105061), it might give you idea to do it another way.

Comment: @Hoki I know this, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, it seems that there is some problem with the rendering under linux or at least my opengl version. There is a workaround that solves the problem for me: Instead of using a texture with transparency, I combine the height and intensity data to an rgb-image and use this as the texture:

```
figure;

% Get some data
[x,y,z] = peaks(128);
pos = (rand(2,5).*4)-2;
i = zeros(128,128);
for n = 1:5
    i = i+exp(-((((x-pos(1,n))/.2).^2+(((y-pos(2,n)))/.2).^2))); 
end

% Convert to uin16 since real data is uint16
i = i./max(i(:));
i = i * 2^16;
i = uint16(i);

% Do the same with the z-data

z_idx = z - min(z(:));
z_idx = z_idx / max(z_idx(:));
z_idx = uint16(2^16 * z_idx );

i_rgb = ind2rgb(i, hot(2^16));
z_rgb = ind2rgb(z_idx, gray(2^16));

% merge the images using i as alpha values.

alphas = double(i)/2^16;
alphas_inv = ones(size(alphas)) - alphas;

% Display data

merged_rgb = zeros(size(i,1), size(i,2), 3);

for channel = 1:3
    merged_rgb(:,:,channel) = z_rgb(:,:,channel).*alphas_inv + i_rgb(:,:,channel) .* alphas;
end

s = surface(x,y,z);
s.EdgeColor = 'none';
s.FaceColor='texturemap';
s.CData = merged_rgb;
```

This yields the expected result
[image]