# Scatter plot on top of a surface plot has garbled points

Tags: matlab, plot

I have the following code that overlays a scatter plot on a surface.
Notice that some of the rounded points are chopped off.

```
figure
scatter(rand(20,1)*10,...
        rand(20,1)*20,...
        'o', 'LineWidth',5, ...
        'MarkerFaceColor', 'black', ...
        'MarkerEdgeColor', 'black')
hold on
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:0.5:10,1:20);
Z = sin(X) + cos(Y);
surf(X,Y,Z)
view(2)
axis equal square;
```

Here is the output:
[image]

Comment: I can reproduce (R2017b on Win 10). The effect changes as the window is resized

Comment: shouldn't be a problem if you use two 3D-plotting functions => `scatter3` and make it a 3D plot in the first place

Comment: I know you already have a valid answer, but I feel obliged to link this question to a very similar one : [MATLAB: Drawing atop a surface plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40056735/3460361). Have a look there, some answers might interest you too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**That's actually not a bug**. It happens because you use surf which is a 3D plotting tool, and overlay it with small spheres at the height Z=0 generated by the scatter plot. Some of the spheres are cut by the 2d surface manifold at Z=0, some are below the manifold. Choosing `view(2)` show the part of the scatter plot that is only above the manifold that surf created (or that the surf Z values are <0) .

Change to `view(3)` and play with the camera angles to see it:

[image]

If you want to overlay a scatter plot on the surf data, you can, but you need to take a different path, here are a few suggestions:

1. add transparency to the surface plot, for example add `alpha(0.5)` after the surf line in your code and see...
2. add an artificial Z value to the surf  plot so it will not intersect with the scatter plot at Z=0, for example edit the following line to : `Z = sin(X) + cos(Y)-pi;` ...
3. plot it differently (first using imagesc then scatter), for example:

   ```
   [X,Y] = meshgrid(1:0.5:10,1:20);
   Z = sin(X) + cos(Y);
   imagesc(1:0.5:10,1:20,Z) % the same meshgrid values are used

   hold on 
   scatter(rand(20,1)*10,...
   rand(20,1)*20,...
   'o', 'LineWidth',5, ...
   'MarkerFaceColor', 'black', ...
   'MarkerEdgeColor', 'black')

    axis equal square;
   ```